# How to start service 'package' with ADB

Tags: adb, system-apps, services

Using adb, I uninstalled some system apps on my device. Sadly, I uninstalled something important, and now the device is in a bootloop.

During boot there is a window of time which I'm able to login with adb. But when I try to reinstall the system apps:

```
adb shell cmd package install-existing --user 0 com.xyzname
```

I get this error:

```
Can't find service: package
```

I used to be able to run install/uninstall commands in this bootup window, but now the service 'package' isn't being started.

I tried looking up how to run services with adb, and I found [some commands using `am`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415997/how-to-start-and-stop-android-service-from-a-adb-shell/18703083), but nothing pertaining to specifically running 'package'.

I need to get service 'package' to run. Begging for help here.

Comment: See if you can run this command: `adb shell pm install-existing --user 0 com.xyzname`. If that doesn't work either, you have to do a factory reset because I am assuming you don't have a custom recovery (which at least offers a way out in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly it doesn't work, I don't have custom recovery. The service package needs to be running ☹️

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and finally got it to work by adding `su -c`.

For your case, it should be:

```
adb shell su -c cmd package install-existing --user 0 com.xyzname
```